# Add spacing between axis and start point

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to add spacing between `0` and `March` in the x axis so that it looks better.

*startdate* and *enddate* are calculated by `d3.min` and `d3.max`.

So those columns looks bad because of their width.

```
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);

var datestart = d3.min(data, function(d) { return parseDate(d.date); });
var dateend = d3.max(data, function(d) { return parseDate(d.date);});

x.domain([datestart, dateend]);
```

[image]

How can I do this? How to add a padding using `d3.scaleTime()`?

Comment: scaleband() has padding() func, but scaletime() hasn't

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50243112/add-spacing-between-axis-and-start-point-d3-js-v4#comment87504222_50243112) (maybe a reply?), there is no padding in a time scale.

Therefore, the problem here is one that from time to time (no pun intended) appears at SO: you are using the wrong tool for the task. Bar charts should always use a categorical (qualitative) scale, not a quantitative scale or a time scale.

However, if you really need to use the time scale here (for whatever reason), you can add the padding in the domain, using [offset](https://github.com/d3/d3-time#interval_offset).

For instance, this will subtract 15 days at the beginning of your domain, and add 15 days at the end:

```
var datestart = d3.min(data, function(d) { 
    return d3.timeDay.offset(parseDate(d.date), -15);
    //subtract 15 days here ---------------------^ 
});

var dateend = d3.max(data, function(d) { 
    return d3.timeDay.offset(parseDate(d.date), 15);
    //add 15 days here -------------------------^
});
```

You can tweak that value until you have an adequate padding. As I don't know how you are calculating the width of the bars (again, bars should not be used in a time scale), 15 days is just a guess here.